# Effect of pH on solubility (Lehninger's Principles)

Tags: acid-base

The following problem is found in Lehninger's 8 Ed.:

[image]

I understand the reasoning in the problem statement: in a basic solution, more of the acid dissociates, and this dissolves, since the ionized form is soluble.

**Applying the same reasoning to item (a), which concerns a similar (same pKa) weak acid, I conclude that it would be more soluble in aq. NaOH, however the answer key says the opposite.**

The answers to the other items seem likewise "inverted".

[image]

I cannot understand how this isn't contradicting.

Comment: You have to consider whether the protonated species or the deprotonated species is the neutral form.

Comment: Please use text instead of text screenshots and cite the textbook correctly. Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Answer (score 0):

Theere is an error in this question. The error is it has given protonated versions of  quinoline and (2-methylthio)pyridine. That two, since they are already protonated, should dissolve in aqueous solvents. Also, as OP expected, they should also react with $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ since they contain acidic proton.

The question should have been asked using nutral form of structures as:

> Categorize the given compounds, quinoline, *m*-cresol, and (2-methylthio)pyridine, whether they are more soluble in an aqueous solution of $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{NaOH}$ or $\pu{0.1 M}$ $\ce{HCl}$.

Then, anybody can answer it using principles of $\mathrm{pH}$ on solubility.